# How should I handle animation states in Mecanim?

Tags: 2d, unity, architecture, animation, mecanim

I did a tutorial which associated an integer to each state and manually set transitions from one state to another based on that integer, but that seems really sloppy.

Is there a more elegant way? I want to be able to change animations from code.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if you have seen this but i found this very usefull

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/212172-Animator-state-machine-for-top-down-2d-games-with-non-rotational-sprite-animation

From a Unity dev:

> One way to go about this is to have 2D blendtree for each movement (example: idle, walk, run, ...)

[image]

The unity dev explains further:

> Even though not their original purpose, the 2D blendtree to group 8 different directions of same animation is very convenient. This allows you to keep your state machine very simple (see screenshots). The "blend" is just a discrete change from one sprite anim to another, but that doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It is preferred to duplicate most or all of the relevant information here, both to avoid link rot and to keep the answer's information in the same place as the question's.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 5 you can define behaviours that can be attached to animator states:

```
using UnityEngine;

// Add this to the state in your state machine.
// This behaviour is instantiated ONCE per animator asset NOT per animator component.
public class YourStateMachineBehaviour : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    // You can have fields here, but they are shared amongst all game objects
    // with animators referencing the same state machine asset.
    public int foo = 42;

    public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        var gameObject = animator.gameObject;

        // Do whatever you want here...
    }
}
```

Refer to the Unity documentation for further information:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours